# How to choose columns for Partitioning and bucketing in hive Table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, partitioning

What will be the ideal columns for partitioning and bucketing for the below schema? Is it necessary to implement both or one is good to go?

```
user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
product_id VARCHAR(20),
gender ENUM('M','F') default NULL,
age VARCHAR(6),
occupation TINYINT UNSIGNED default NULL,
city_category ENUM('A','B','C','D','E') default NULL,
stay_in_current_city_years VARCHAR(6),
martial_status TINYINT UNSIGNED default 0,
product_category_1 TINYINT UNSIGNED default 0,
product_category_2 TINYINT  UNSIGNED default 0,
product_category_3 TINYINT UNSIGNED default 0,
purchase_amount INTEGER UNSIGNED default 0
```

The main goal is to do some analysis based on the above attributes using Hive.

Comment: It totally depends on what kind of analysis do you want . As it is not necessary to do partitioning and bucketing both in a single table  So if you can elaborate it further that would be helpful to answer your question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In hive, you create a table based on the usage pattern and so you should choose both partitioning the bucketing based on what your Analysis Queries would look like.

However, the following things are advisable

**Partitioning**

- Partitioning helps you speed up the queries with predicates (i.e. Where conditions). So in your case, if `city_category` is the field you are going to use most of the time in your where condition you should choose that field for partition.
- It might degrade the performance of other queries.
- Need to make sure that cardinality is not too high, otherwise, your query performance would be degraded.

To understand the above points you need to understand how partitioning works.  When you create a partition (or subpartition), Hive creates a subfolder with that name and stores the data (files) into those folders.

So if you partition based on `city_category` your file would look like this.

```
/data/table_name/city_category=A
/data/table_name/city_category=B
...
/data/table_name/city_category=E
```

This helps hive to find a particular record if you provide `city_category` in `Where condition` as it has to just scan one folder.

However, if you try to find a record based on `user_id` or `product_id` then hive need to scan all the folders.

And let's say if you end up partitioning based on `purchase_amount`, then you will have a lot many folders. NameNode has to maintain the location of each folder and files and so it will create a lot of load on your NameNode and obviously decrease the performance of your query.

**Bucketing**

- It helps you in speeding up your join query if another table you are joining has similar bucketing.
- However, it's a good idea to make sure data is distributed evenly in bucketing.

What bucketing does it, it applies a hashing on a given field and based on that it stores the given record in bucketing.

So let's say if you bucket based on `city_category` and tell to create 50 buckets.

```
CLUSTERED BY (city_category) INTO 50 BUCKETS
```

as we have only 5 categories, other 45 buckets would be empty, this is something you don't want as it will degrade the performance of your query.